# Maximo Anywhere New Table access

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Am working on Anywhere 7.5.2 (Work Execution app). In MAM, A new table is created, I need to access that table in anywhere. How to do the same.
Ex: WORKORDER is an existing table, WORKORDERFLOW is the new table.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very similar to this example

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.6.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/config_apps/t_add_rel_records.html

Except instead of extending the existing OSLCWODETAIL object structure, you create a NEW object structure and bring that over into your application.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.